# Used unique inside email index Mongodb, cannot alert 'user already registered'

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

unique:true does stop from adding to database, but only getting the catch(e) error message. Tried using the findOne method, but as a beginner, architecture keeps messing me up.

```
require('dotenv').config()
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const app = express();

const urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })
app.use(bodyParser.json(), urlencodedParser);
app.use(cors());

const dbURI = 
`mongodb+srv://${process.env.REACT_APP_DB_USERNAME}:${process.env.REACT_APP_DB_PASSWORD}@cluster0.sd1id.mongodb.net/register?retryWrites=true&w=majority`

mongoose.connect(dbURI, { useNewUrlParser:true, useUnifiedTopology:true })
.then((res) => {

    const User = mongoose.model('users', UsersSchema);
User.createIndexes();
```

Having issues here I think. Goes straight to error, and not the else loop.

```
app.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const user = new User(req.body);
        let result = await user.save();
        result = result.toObject();
        // console.log(result);
        if (result) {
            delete result.password;
            res.send(req.body);
            // console.log(result);
        } else {
            console.log("User already registered!");
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Something went wrong!");
    }
})

})
.catch(err => console.log(err))

const UsersSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true,
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    }
})



app.listen(3001, () => console.log("Server is listening to port 3001"))
```

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: when I post a new user, I expected the console.log("user already registered"), but if console.log("something went wrong")

Comment: I could just switch the two console.log messages, but seeing why the else statement gets avoided

Comment: You can see the actual error message if you `console.log(e)`. Then you can find what the real issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bit of confusion in your code...

app.js

```
require('dotenv').config()
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const app = express();

const createUser = require('registerController');

// repleace 3000 with a port number of your choice
const port = 3000 || process.env.PORT;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

app.post('/register', createUser);

const dbURI = 
`mongodb+srv://${process.env.REACT_APP_DB_USERNAME}:${process.env.REACT_APP_DB_PASSWORD}@cluster0.sd1id.mongodb.net/register?retryWrites=true&w=majority`

mongoose.connect(dbURI, { useNewUrlParser:true, useUnifiedTopology:true })
.then(() => {
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server listening on Port ${port}`));
});
```

User.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true,
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

registerController.js

```
const User = require('User');

const createUser = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const user = await User.create(req.body);
        // console.log(user);
        if (user) {
            delete user.password;
            res.send(req.body);
            // console.log(user);
        } else {
            console.log("User already registered!");
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Something went wrong!");
    }
};

module.exports = createUser;
```

Comment: Thanks so much for cleaning up my structure~
Makes it easier to check my errors

Comment: @Haejinyi No worries : )